# Sorry, name cannot contain leading or trailing spaces and name can only contain URL-friendly characters

Tags: node.js

i'm new at this and im trying to create a realtime chat application with json and socket.io. I was installed Node.js and when type `npm init`- to create and install package.json file  it gives me: "Sorry, name can only contain URL-friendly characters."! I am typing this in Micsorosft visual studio code. And when i type `npm install` it gives me "Sorry, name cannot contain leading or trailing spaces and name can only contain URL-friendly characters." And my asking is what i need to do to set the directory. thanks previously! this is a part of the code JS code.

```
var app = require('express')(3000);
var http = require('http').createServer(app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: Can you add the package.json file to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your `name` field in your `package.json` most probably contains invalid characters.

Only use lowercase alpha characters and hyphens for separation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to finish the package creating process (npm init) first and then move to dependencies installation process (npm install). Enter a name to the package or if you think that the suggested name in the parenthesis is reasonable, (***package name: (suggestedpacakagename)***)  you can directly hit return.